# Reconversion txt file (from Windows to Unix)

Tags: java, utf-8, type-conversion, prediction

My university project written in Java, take tweets from Twitter and analyzes them.

In the first phase, I take tweets; I have to do that on a Windows machine, after I put online on my Linux server program and I use it to analyze tweets with a user feedback system.

When I open the txt file on Linux machine, it asks me if I want convert in `UTF-8`, and I click yes. But because of this operation some special characters are not formatted correctly. If I try to reconvert in original format (maybe `CP1252`) with *iconv* it returns an error caused by special characters.

I understand that it is impossible to reconvert that characters, because any special character is a sum of the possible character that they may be, but I can use a sort of text predict character to rewrite that character`?`.

For example if I have `because`, and `e` is a special character I see this word something like this `becaus?`, If I remove the `?` character, how can I reput the `e`? I have tried to use Word but the txt is too big, so there a big mount of words with this problem, and with Word you have to check every word manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dos2unix` to change the file to linux format